# MediaMuxer sometimes resulting in black video

Tags: android, h.264, encoder, mediamuxer, muxer

I am using AndroidEncoder to produce a H264 video with AAC audio that I send both over an RTMP network and also store locally in a MP4 file using MediaMuxer.

Broadcasting is working nicely over RTMP, but when saving locally the resulting video is sometimes okay, sometimes its just black frames with sound (or just a first partial frame with some blocks of information), and sometimes it plays first the audio, then the video with random FPS speeds.

This is the output shown by my Muxer wrapper class and the MPEG4Writer SDK class:

```
02-28 11:57:38.521 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: addTrack: Requested adding of track to class AndroidMuxer of type AUDIO
02-28 11:57:38.522 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: addTrack: Adding track for audio/mp4a-latm
02-28 11:57:38.522 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: addTrack: Track index to class AndroidMuxer of type AUDIO, track saved for future use!
02-28 11:57:38.621 6420-6470/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: addTrack: Requested adding of track to class AndroidMuxer of type VIDEO
02-28 11:57:38.621 6420-6470/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: addTrack: Adding track for video/avc
02-28 11:57:38.621 6420-6470/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: addTrack: All tracks added, marking Local muxer as ready!
02-28 11:57:38.622 6420-6470/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: addTrack: Track index to class AndroidMuxer of type VIDEO, track saved for future use!
02-28 11:57:52.050 6420-6420/com.myapp.broadcast I/AndroidMuxer: init: Added audio track widh id 0
02-28 11:57:52.050 6420-6420/com.myapp.broadcast I/AndroidMuxer: init: Added video track widh id 1
02-28 11:57:52.050 6420-6420/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: init: Muxer was successfully created! Starting to record
02-28 11:57:52.056 6420-6420/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: limits: 4294967295/0 bytes/us, bit rate: -1 bps and the estimated moov size 3195 bytes
02-28 11:57:52.057 6420-6420/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: start: Muxer started!
02-28 11:57:52.070 6420-6965/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: setStartTimestampUs: 0
02-28 11:57:52.070 6420-6965/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: Earliest track starting time: 0
02-28 11:57:52.083 6420-6966/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: setStartTimestampUs: 0
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: writeSampleData: All tracks finished! Calling Stop
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: stop: Calling stop to the muxer
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Audio track stopping
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Audio track source stopping
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Audio track source stopped
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6965/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: Received total/0-length (452/0) buffers and encoded 452 frames. - Audio
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6965/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: Audio track drift time: 0 us
02-28 11:58:02.617 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Audio track stopped
02-28 11:58:02.618 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping
02-28 11:58:02.618 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Video track source stopping
02-28 11:58:02.618 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Video track source stopped
02-28 11:58:02.618 6420-6966/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: Received total/0-length (315/0) buffers and encoded 315 frames. - Video
02-28 11:58:02.618 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopped
02-28 11:58:02.618 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Duration from tracks range is [10143021, 10495420] us
02-28 11:58:02.618 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Stopping writer thread
02-28 11:58:02.620 6420-6964/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: 0 chunks are written in the last batch
02-28 11:58:02.620 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast D/MPEG4Writer: Writer thread stopped
02-28 11:58:02.621 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast I/MPEG4Writer: The mp4 file will not be streamable.
02-28 11:58:02.621 6420-6475/com.myapp.broadcast W/AndroidMuxer: stop: muxer stopped!
```

Not that while the video saved locally is not okay, the live stream of the same footage (resulting from the same encoding process) is fine, so the problem must be in the muxer itself (or, more precisely, in the way I handle it).

This is my Muxer Wrapper (heavily inspired by bigflake's [mediacodec samples](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/)):

```
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

/**
 * @hide
 */
public class AndroidMuxer extends Muxer {
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidMuxer";
    private static final boolean VERBOSE = false;

    private MediaMuxer mMuxer;
    private boolean mStarted = false;
    private boolean mStopped = false;
    private boolean mReadyToStart;
    private MediaFormat mVideoTrackFormat;
    private MediaFormat mAudioTrackFormat;

    private long mStartTimeUs = 0;
    @Override
    public void reset() {
        Log.w(TAG, "reset: Reset is called on LOCAL MUXER!");

            mStarted = false;
            mReadyToStart = false;
            mNumTracks = 0;
            mNumTracksFinished = 0;
            Log.w(TAG, "reset: Reset worked on the Muxer");

    }

    /**
     * This will only initialize the fields, we only want the real muxer to be initialized
     * when we go live.
     * @param outputFile outputPath of the file
     * @param format Format of the muxer (will always be MPEG4 TBH)
     */
    public AndroidMuxer(String outputFile, FORMAT format) {
        super(outputFile, format);
        mStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        if(!mReadyToStart) {
            return;
        }

        if(mStarted){
            Log.i(TAG, "init: Muxer already created! Skipping!");
            return;
        }


        try {
            switch (mFormat) {
                case MPEG4:
                    mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(mOutputPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
                    int audioTrack = mMuxer.addTrack(mAudioTrackFormat);
                    Log.i(TAG, "init: Added audio track widh id " + audioTrack);
                    mAudioTrackIndex = audioTrack;

                    int videoTrack = mMuxer.addTrack(mVideoTrackFormat);
                    Log.i(TAG, "init: Added video track widh id " + videoTrack);
                    mVideoTrackIndex = videoTrack;
                    Log.w(TAG, "init: Muxer was successfully created! Starting to record");
                    start();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized format!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("MediaMuxer creation failed", e);
        }
    }

    public static AndroidMuxer create(String outputFile, FORMAT format) {
        return new AndroidMuxer(outputFile, format);
    }

    @Override
    public int addTrack(MediaFormat trackFormat, AndroidEncoder.TrackType trackType) {
        Log.w(TAG, "addTrack: Requested adding of track to class " + getClass().getSimpleName() + " of type " + trackType);
        //Super method just keeps track of amount of tracks added
        super.addTrack(trackFormat, trackType);
        Log.w(TAG, "addTrack: Adding track for " + trackFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME));
        if (mStarted)
            throw new RuntimeException("format changed twice");

        //What we do is store the media info for later use once the muxer is created.
        //This is done to prevent file creation until the event goes live.

        if(trackType == AndroidEncoder.TrackType.VIDEO){
            mVideoTrackFormat = trackFormat;
        }
        else if(trackType == AndroidEncoder.TrackType.AUDIO){
            mAudioTrackFormat = trackFormat;
        }



        if (allTracksAdded()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "addTrack: All tracks added, marking Local muxer as ready!");
            markReadyToStart();
        }
        Log.w(TAG, "addTrack: Track index to class " + getClass().getSimpleName() + " of type " + trackType + ", track saved for future use!");
        //Return dummy
        return 1;
    }


    /**
     *
     * Marking the Muxer as ready to be started but not yet!
     *
     */
    private void markReadyToStart() {
        mReadyToStart = true;
    }



    private void start() {
        if(mStarted){
            Log.i(TAG, "start: Skipped start due to muxer already started");
        }
        mStartTimeUs = 0;
        mMuxer.start();
        Log.w(TAG, "start: Muxer started!");
        mStarted = true;
    }

    protected void stop() {
        if(mStarted) {
            Log.w(TAG, "stop: Calling stop to the muxer");
            mMuxer.stop();
            Log.w(TAG, "stop: muxer stopped!");
            mStarted = false;
            mStopped = true;
            mReadyToStart = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void release() {
        super.release();
        if(mStopped) {
            mMuxer.release();
            mStopped = false;
            mStarted = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return mStarted;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSampleData(MediaCodec encoder, int trackIndex, int bufferIndex, ByteBuffer encodedData, MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo) {
        if(!mStarted) {

            return;
        }

        super.writeSampleData(encoder, trackIndex, bufferIndex, encodedData, bufferInfo);
        if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
            // MediaMuxer gets the codec config info via the addTrack command
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG");
            return;
        }

        if (bufferInfo.size == 0) {
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "ignoring zero size buffer");
            return;
        }

        if (!mStarted) {
            Log.w(TAG, "writeSampleData called before muxer started. Ignoring packet. Track index: " + trackIndex + " tracks added: " + mNumTracks);
//            encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(bufferIndex, false);
            return;
        }

//        bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = getNextRelativePts(bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs, trackIndex);


       if(mStartTimeUs == 0) {
              mStartTimeUs = bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;
             }
        bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs -= mStartTimeUs;
        if(bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs < 0) {
             bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = 0;
        }
        bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = getSafePts(bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs, trackIndex);


        mMuxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedData, bufferInfo);

//        encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(bufferIndex, false);

        if (allTracksFinished()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "writeSampleData: All tracks finished! Calling Stop");
            stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void forceStop() {
        Log.w(TAG, "forceStop: ForceStop called!");
        stop();
    }
}
```

Note that RTMP muxer and Local muxer might not start working at the same time, thats why I store the media info and then use it only when the user requests the muxer to be started.

Answer (score 1):

If the local muxer is not ready yet and you skip writing packets, you might skip writing a keyframe. Later video frames that are not a keyframe can't be decoded until you reach the next keyframe (and who knows if a video player might get confused if the file starts with a non-keyframe?). If you have a long interval between keyframes, you might not get a keyframe at all within some reasonable time. (Although, if you are streaming this over RTMP as well, you probably have keyframes regularly.)

My advice would be to make sure to either store all the packets that are produced before the local muxer is ready, and write them to the local muxer once it is ready, or then keep skipping packets until you reach the next keyframe.

Comment: Cannot do that, my app is designed so that you can start live broadcasting and then choose any moment to start recording locally. What I can do, though, is only start feeding the local encoder when I receive a keyframe. However I'm not sure this is the problem because if this was the issue then  a) I would almost never get a keyframe as first frame, and thus I wouldnt almost ever be able to have a proper recording and b) I think if this was the problem then I may get 2 black seconds and then video would resume properly once I get a keyframe (I have GOP set to every 2 secs).

Comment: I will, however, try this approach. This does not explain either, I think, why I sometimes get first audio, then all the video on some locally recorded files.